How can I use DuckDB together with DbVisualizer?
I want to use DuckDB together with DbVisualizer. On the website of DuckDB I only see a guide for DBeaver, but this does not work on DbVisualizer.

First add a new maven repository in Tools -> Tool Properties -> Driver Manager with these settings:

URL: https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/
ID: duckdb

Then go to Tools -> Driver Manager and look for the driver "Custom" in the templates list. Right click on "Custom" and select the only available option "Create User Driver from Template".
In "Driver Settings" use DuckDB as Name and "jdbc:duckdb::memory:" as URL format. Driver class is not yet selectable, so use the "+" in section driver artifacts and chose option "Add artifact". In the new small popup enter these values:

Group ID: org.duckdb
Artifact ID: duckdb_jdbc

If everything works correctly, you should be able to select a version in the dropdown (may take a moment until DbVisualizer receives all infos). Use "1.0.0" as value and press OK.
Voilá, that's it. Now you should be able to create a new database connection using this new user specific driver. When creating a new connection, you may have to enter jdbc:duckdb::memory: once again, and you have your own in-memory DuckDB database.
